# Derived QPainterPath, QPainter performance degrading quickly

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I am currently trying to encapsulate my QPainter objects into reusable classes, possibly deriving each other. This enables them to transform the painter around any way they like, have their own children to draw etc:

I have `DrawArc` derived from `QPainterPath`

```
DrawArc::DrawArc() : QPainterPath()
{}

void DrawArc::paint(QPainter* painter)
{
    painter->save();
    //...
    arcTo(/*...*/);
    lineTo(/*...*/);
    painter->translate(QPoint(100,100));
    painter->drawPath(*dynamic_cast<QPainterPath*>(this));
    painter->restore();
}
```

and `DrawBeam` derived from `DrawArc`

```
DrawBeam::DrawBeam() : DrawArc()
{}

void DrawBeam::paint(QPainter* painter)
{
    painter->save();
    //...
    painter->setPen(QPen(color, 4));
    painter->setBrush(brush);
    DrawArc::paint(painter);
    painter->restore();
}
```

In the actual Widget I am doing the following

```
BeamWidget::BeamWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    DrawBeam* mybeam = new DrawBeam();
}

void BeamWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

    mybeam->paint(&painter);
}
```

However I am seeing dramatic performance losses in `painter->drawPath(*dynamic_cast<QPainterPath*>(this));` after a few seconds (or few hundred redraws). Everything else in the remaining procedure seems to run fine but when I enable that line the performance degrades quickly.

Also all elements deriving from `DrawArc` painting seem to sometimes lose their QBrush styles and remain visible even though `setAutoFillBackground(true);` is set...

Comment: `Also all elements deriving from DrawArc painting seem to sometimes lose their QBrush styles` you are saving the painter...

Comment: to my knowledge `painter->save()` and `painter->restore()` let me take a snapshot of my painter so I can unroll back to it when I am done, undoing all transformations and unsetting the picked pens, brushes etc.

Comment: it opens the possibility of using different styles during painting.

Comment: btw the performance loss compared to what? It seems there is no alternative in your post.

Comment: Compared to right after the program starts. No data is being changed but repeated paints make the successive paints become slower.

Comment: can you edit to show for instance what DrawBeam can do on the painter? you understand that `QPainterPath` originally dont act on `QPainter` right? actually `QPainter` doesnt even exists from `QPainterPath` perspective

Comment: I've added some examples. Basic stuff like transformations, rotation, pen and brush settings etc.

Comment: First of all replace "dynamic_cast" by "static_cast", it will improve performance

Comment: I tried that already, it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this has to do with me only creating the object once, then adding an `arcTo` and a few other lines to it **during each run of `paint()`**. Since I can't flush the QPainterPath the Path simply becomes longer and longer and longer and longer.

This explains why old lines are not being flushed and why the brush is alternating (each time I re-draw the same thing I am forming a new intersection with the path itself, wich by design is not being filled).

I fixed it like this:

```
void DrawArc::paint(QPainter* painter)
{
    painter->save();
    //...

    QPainterPath path = QPainterPath(*this);
    path.arcTo(/*...*/);
    path.lineTo(/*...*/);

    painter->translate(QPoint(100,100));
    painter->drawPath(path);
    painter->restore();
}
```

So in each drawing operation I create a copy of the current path, add all lines I need to it and paint that one. After exiting `paint`, that drawn path is being discarded.